# How to balance (oversampling) unbalanced data in PyTorch (with WeightedRandomSampler)?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, data-cleaning

I have a 2-class problem and my data is highly unbalanced. I have 232550 samples from one class and `13498` from the second class. PyTorch docs and the internet tells me to use the class WeightedRandomSampler for my DataLoader.

I have tried using the WeightedRandomSampler but I keep getting errors.

```
    trainratio = np.bincount(trainset.labels)
    classcount = trainratio.tolist()
    train_weights = 1./torch.tensor(classcount, dtype=torch.float)
    train_sampleweights = train_weights[trainset.labels]
    train_sampler = WeightedRandomSampler(weights=train_sampleweights, 
    num_samples = len(train_sampleweights))
    trainloader = DataLoader(trainset, sampler=train_sampler, 
    shuffle=False)
```

I can not see why I am getting this error when initializing the WeightedRandomSampler class?

I have tried other similar workarounds but so far all attempts produce some error.
How should I implement this to balance my train, validation and test data?

Currently getting this error:

> train__sampleweights = train_weights[trainset.labels] ValueError: too
>   many dimensions 'str'

Comment: You should always post a reproducible example of your code. what type is trainset.labels? which are its dimensions?

Comment: trainset.labels is a list of labels like [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,.....] containing all the training labels.

Comment: Given the error message I would check: 1) are the labels strings? 2) which are the dimensions of train_weights?

Comment: Thanks @Roberto. So I checked 1). Labels were strings, so I converted to float - this fixed that ' ValueError: too many dimensions 'str'' error. 2). weights shape=  torch.Size([246048]) that is the number of train samples I have.
Now I get this error:
UserWarning: To copy construct from a tensor, it is recommended to use sourceTensor.clone().detach() or sourceTensor.clone().detach().requires_grad_(True), rather than torch.tensor(sourceTensor).
  self.weights = torch.tensor(weights, dtype=torch.double)

Comment: That is great. I will post an answer to help those that will look for a similar issue.
For the new error please open another post. Is in the rule of stakoverflow that each post should address a question.

Comment: Thank you. I will do that :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the type of trainset.labels
To fix the error it is possible to convert trainset.labels to float

Comment: Please add an example.